# How to convert Android drawables to IOS?

Tags: android, ios, user-interface, uiview, android-drawable

I just began trying to convert my Android app to IOS and was wondering how I can convert my Android XML drawables. The goal is to be able to create textures using shapes with x and y positions so that the texture is not stretched. Is there a similar thing to Android drawables in IOS? If not how would I use the textures created from the drawables in IOS? For example how would I convert the drawable for a textbox below?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="10dp" android:left="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" android:right="0dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:height="13dp"
                android:width="46dp"
                />
            <solid
                android:color="@color/grey"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="0dp" android:left="0dp" android:bottom="10dp" android:right="0dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:height="13dp"
                android:width="46dp"
                />
            <solid
                android:color="@color/very_light_grey"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="0dp" android:left="2dp" android:bottom="0dp" android:right="2dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:height="13dp"
                android:width="46dp"
                />
            <solid
                android:color="@color/grey"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="1dp" android:left="3dp" android:bottom="3dp" android:right="3dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:height="20dp"
                android:width="40dp"
            />
            <solid
                android:color="@color/white"
           />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: You should probably take a look at `UIBezierPath` - https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibezierpath. It isn't similar in implementation - but similar in results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIBezierPath is the closest thing to Android Drawables that I was able to find. Although it is not in XML like Android Drawables, the functionality is very similar to Android Drawables where you can use basic shapes to create textures for UI components.The conversion of the Android Drawable in the question is displayed below:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class CustomUIInputText : UITextField{
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
}
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let darkGrey = ColorUtilities.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "808080")
    let lightGrey = ColorUtilities.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "efefef")
    let lightGreyRect = UIBezierPath(rect: rect)
    let width = rect.size.width
    let height = rect.size.height
    let yValue = rect.origin.y
    let xValue = rect.origin.x
    lightGrey.setFill()
    lightGreyRect.fill()
    let darkGreyRect = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: xValue, y:yValue + ((2 * height)/3), width: width, height: height/3))
    darkGrey.setFill()
    darkGreyRect.fill()
    let darkGreyRect2 = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: xValue+3, y:yValue, width: width - 6, height: height))
    darkGrey.setFill()
    darkGreyRect2.fill()
    let whiteRect = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: xValue + 4, y:yValue + 1, width: width - 8, height: height - 4))
    UIColor.white.setFill()
    whiteRect.fill()
}
}
```